# How to use a partial view to add rows to a table defined in the main view

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have the below table definition in my MVC 3 main view.

```
 <table id="myDynamicTable" class="myClass" >
            <thead>
                <tr id="uploadrow_0">
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;width: 5px; text-align: left " >
                        Number
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;width: 120px; text-align: left ">
                        Unit
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;text-align: left ">
                        Type
                    </th>
                    <th  style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;width: 90px; text-align: left ">
                        Date
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;width: 351px; text-align: left ">
                        Action
                    </th>
                    <th style="white-space: nowrap;display: inline;width: 300px; text-align: left ">
                        Comment
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                          @if (Model.ProductDetails.Count > 0)
                          {
                              foreach (var item in Model.ProductDetails)
                              {
                                  @Html.Partial("ProductDetailsPartial", item);
                              }
                          }
                          else
                          {
                              ProductDetailsViewModel item = new ProductDetailsViewModel();
                              item.Types = ViewBag.TypeList;
                              item.Unit = ViewBag.UnitList;
                              item.Number = 1;
                              @Html.Partial("ProductDetailsPartial", item);
                          }

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I'm adding rows dynamically to the above table but each row that i add is being generated from a partial view.

Below is my partial view definition

```
    @model ProductDetailsViewModel
        <tr>
        @using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("item"))
        {
            <td class="autoGenNumber" style="width: 5px" >
                @if (Model == null)
                {
                    ProductDetailsViewModel item = new ProductDetailsViewModel();
                    item.Types = ViewBag.TypeList;
                    item.Unit = ViewBag.UnitList;
                    item.Number = 1;
                   @Html.LabelFor(x => Model.Number, Model.Number.ToString(), new { style = "width: 10px;", @class = "autoGenNumber" })
                }  
            </td>
            <td class="tdUnit">
                @Html.TextBox("Unit", Model.Unit, new { id = "Unit", style = "width:120px; padding: 0px;", @class = "txtUnit" })    
            </td>
            <td class="tdBorder">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TypeId, new SelectList(Model.Types, "Value", "Text", Model.TypeId), "[--Select--]", new { @id = "ddlType", style = "width:20px; padding: 0px;", @class = "ddlType" })
            </td>
            <td class="tdBorder">
                @if (Model.Date.ToShortDateString().Contains("1/1/0001"))
                {
                    <input type="text" name="Model.Date" value="@DateTime.Today.ToShortDateString()"  class="txtDate" readonly = "readonly" style = "width: 90px; padding: 0px;" />
                }
                else
                {
                    <input type="text" name="Model.Date" value="@Model.Date.ToShortDateString()"  class="txtDate" readonly = "readonly" style = "width: 90px; padding: 0px;" />
                }
            </td>
            <td class="tdBorder">
              @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.UnitId, new SelectList(Model.Unit, "Value", "Text", Model.UnitId), "[--Select--]", new { @id = "ddlUnit", style = "width:351px;", @class = "ddlUnit" })
            </td>
            <td class="tdBorder">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.comment, new { id = "Comment", @class = "Comment RestrictCharacters", style = "width:300px;" })
            </td>
        } 
 </tr>
```

The table lay out is coming correctly in IE 8 & above but in chrome and Firefox the Row columns are not properly aligned with the table column headers.

How can i render my partial view as a valid table row in my main view's   **`</tbody>  </tbody>`** element

Below is the screenshot of how my table is appearing in IE (correct layout)

[image]

And below is the incorrect lay out in chrome

[image]

Comment: Try changing the style in the first textbox to `style = "width:120px; padding: 0px; box-sizing:border-box;"` and see if it makes a difference (or reduce the width to say `width: 100px`)

Comment: provide css. you have classes for td.

Comment: @StephenMuecke still no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably `display: inline;` on headers is causing this kind of effect.

Normally table cells have `display:table-cell;`.

Your table headers should look something like:

```
<th style="white-space: nowrap;width: 120px; text-align: left ">
   Unit
</th>
```

Comment: You saved my day. Replacing inline with table-cell as you suggested resolved it.